# Sql Query Issue 'BatchRelease.BatchReleaseNo' is invalid in the select list

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below query when i execute it throws error "Column 'BatchRelease.BatchReleaseNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." Please me to solve the issue.This error occurs when i sum the values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT BR.BatchReleaseNo,BR.CreatedOn,P.ProductName,
        BRD.BatchReleaseQuantity,P.ProductCode,BOED.NoOfEmployee,
        BOED.TimeInHours,EM.EmployeeType,BRPD.ProcessLoss,
        MP.UnitProcessTime,MM.RequiredCostPerHour,
        MM.MachineryType,
        (BRD.BatchReleaseQuantity*BRD.UnitPrice) AS BatchCompletionValue,
        ISNULL(
               SUM((BOED.NoOfEmployee
                    *(BOED.TimeInHours/60 )/60)
                    *(EM.CostPerDay/EM.WorkingHours))
               ,0.0
              )

         FROM BatchReleaseDetails BRD 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR ON BR.BatchReleaseID=BRD.BatchReleaseID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Product P ON P.ProductID=BRD.ProductID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchOrderEmployeeDetails BOED ON BOED.BatchReleaseID=BR.BatchReleaseID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeMaster EM ON EM.EmployeeTypeID=BOED.EmployeeTypeID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchReleasedProcessDetails BRPD ON BRPD.BatchReleaseID=BR.BatchReleaseID
        --LEFT OUTER JOIN Process PR ON PR.ProcessID=BRPD.ProcessID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN MachineProcess MP ON MP.ProcessID=BRPD.ProcessID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN MachineMaster MM ON  MM.MachineID=MP.MachineID
        GRoup BY BR.BatchReleaseNo
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: You can't mix regular columns and columns as aggregate function params without also specifying GROUP BY.

Comment: put all columns other than aggregate in group by

Comment: @jarlh, actually he can with window functions

Comment: @jarlh see my edited question still issue exists

Comment: @MosesE, you should group by all columns that are not in SUM fuction:

GRoup BY BR.BatchReleaseNo, BR.CreatedOn,P.ProductName,........etc

Comment: And remove DISTINCT if all group by columns are also in the select list.